# Vue : Echart js how to export chart as image (Vuexy admin.)

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I'm attempting to export the chart as a picture. I just joined eCharts. Can someone explain how the export button operates? I need to download charts as image.

Here's what I try : Do I have something wrong?

```
  <template>
  <b-card title="Data Science">
  <app-echart-bar:option-data="option"/>
  </b-card>
  </template>

<script>
import { BCard } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import AppEchartBar from '@core/components/charts/echart/AppEchartBar.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    BCard,
    AppEchartBar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      option: {
        toolbox: {
          show: true,
          orient: 'vertical',
          left: 'right',
          top: 'center',
          feature: {
            mark: { show: true },
            dataView: { show: true, readOnly: false },
            magicType: { show: true, type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack'] },
            restore: { show: true },
            saveAsImage: { show: true }
          }
        },
        xAxis: [
          {
            type: 'category',
            data: ['FB', 'IN', 'TW', 'YT',],
          },
        ],
        yAxis: [
          {
            type: 'value',
            splitLine: { show: false },
          },
        ],
        grid: {
          left: '40px',
          right: '30px',
          bottom: '30px',
        },
        series: [

          {
            name: 'Available',
            type: 'bar',
            barGap: 0, 
            emphasis: {
              focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [22, 24, 20, 18]
          },

          {
            name: 'Not Available',
            type: 'bar',
            barGap: 0, 
            emphasis: {
              focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [12, 10, 14, 16]
          },

 
        ],
      },
    }
  },
  }
 </script>
```

Comp:

```
<template>
<e-charts
ref="line"
autoresize
:options="option"
theme="theme-color"
auto-resize/>
```

```
<script>
import ECharts from 'vue-echarts'
import 'echarts/lib/component/tooltip'
import 'echarts/lib/component/legend'
import 'echarts/lib/chart/bar'
import theme from './theme.json'

ECharts.registerTheme('theme-color', theme)


export default {   components: {
   ECharts,

 },   props: {
   optionData: {
     type: Object,
     default: null,
   },   },   data() {
   return {
     option: {
       tooltip: {
         trigger: 'axis',
         axisPointer: {
           type: 'shadow',
         },
       },
       toolbox: {
         show: true,
         orient: 'vertical',
         left: 'right',
         top: 'center',
         feature: {
           mark: { show: true },
           dataView: { show: true, readOnly: false },
           magicType: { show: true, type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack'] },
           restore: { show: true },
           saveAsImage: { show: true }
         }
       },
       legend: {
         left: 0,
       },
       grid: this.optionData.grid,
       xAxis: this.optionData.xAxis,
       yAxis: this.optionData.yAxis,
       series: this.optionData.series,
     },
   }   }, }

    </script>
```

The chart created by eCharts is shown below :

[image: eCharts]

Can somebody assist me with adding a button or tell me whether I need to add a script to download an image.

Comment: alternative use vue apexchart instead . its from vuexy . for echart i have same issue , its only right click then save as image , but the toolbox like vue apexchart have download as csv, image , png etc .

Answer (score -1):

the main important is

```
import 'echarts/lib/component/toolbox' // Import toolbox component
import 'echarts/lib/component/export' // Import export component
```

i have tested on echart example with

```
toolbox: {
          show: true,
          feature: {
            saveAsImage: {
              show: true, // Enable export to image functionality
              title: 'Save as Image', // Customize the tooltip title
              name: 'chart',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              pixelRatio: 2
            }
          },
          right: '30px',
          top: '10px'
        },
        // Add export component
        export: {
          show: true,
          title: 'Export', // Customize the tooltip title
          name: 'chart',
          pixelRatio: 2
        },
```

so here full of code

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ],
  toolbox: {
          show: true,
          feature: {
            saveAsImage: {
              show: true, // Enable export to image functionality
              title: 'Save as Image', // Customize the tooltip title
              name: 'chart',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              pixelRatio: 2
            }
          },
          right: '30px',
          top: '10px'
        },
        // Add export component
        export: {
          show: true,
          title: 'Export', // Customize the tooltip title
          name: 'chart',
          pixelRatio: 2
        },
};
```

from : https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple